# How to report precision and recall scores using Mallet command line prompt?

Tags: machine-learning, document-classification, mallet

I'm using MaxEnt classifier from Mallet for text classification. Mallet provides the ability to report the accuracy and F1 scores using the command line prompt.

Is there a way to report precision and recall scores using the command line prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after some investigations, I found out that there is no direct way to report Precision and Recall from the command line. However, it's very easy to do that by using the Mallet interface in your java code as explained in: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/classifier-devel.php